# How to use facebook api to post on pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

First its not a duplicate question.
What i'm currently having is i'm able to Publish Post Facebook page using app key and secret. as my code mention below.

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => $config['App_ID'],
   'secret' => $config['App_Secret'],
   'cookie' => true
    ));

    if(isset($_POST['status']))
    {
    $page = split("-",$_POST['page']);
    $page_token = $page[0];
    $page_id= $page[1];
    // status with link
    $publish = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed', 'post',
            array('access_token' => $page_token,
            'message'=> $_POST['status'],
            'from' => $page_id,
            'to' => $page_id,
            'caption' => 'Caption',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
            'picture' => '',
            'description' => $_POST['status']
            ));
```

The code works perfect its posting on page but the problem I have is i want it to post as my profile name which is on my Facebook ID, but its showing posted by someone and then VIA app name.
to make the concept clear see the image below.

[image]

Comment: If you want to post it as you and not the page use your user access token

Comment: @WizKid Thanks, btw i have tried to use user access token. but no changes

Comment: If you are posting through Facebook API, there is now way yo can avoid 'Posted by <app name>'. That is how Facebook API works as all the actions are done through the Facebook app which is basically authentication any API action.

Comment: @nitigyan If i don't use Facebook App Key Is It Possible to use Access Token To Post On Pages Or Profile For Ignoring 
'Posted by <app name>'. if that is how can i post using a access token which i got from graph api explorer? because i saw many tuts but they were using Facebook App.

Comment: Any access token is based on a Facebook app only. So whenever you use an access token it is anyways posting through app only so you can't avoid the app name

Comment: That is problem, because while testing my pages i saw that i don't get enough reach when i post using app and when ever i post my self i do get much people reach. that's what the main issue.